# Why is the main memory for object allocation called the 'heap'?

Tags: programming-languages, memory, stack, heap

Has anybody got an idea why the area of main memory where objects are allocated is referred to as the heap. I can understand the rationale for that of the stack LIFO but would like to know what the rationale is for the 'heap' name.

Comment: I have zero history or evidence to back this up, but I would wager the stack came first, and in english a heap is basically the antithesis of a stack, so when something came along that wasn't a stack and had no structural guarantees, heap just came to mind for some set of people and it spread like language tends to..

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: You're probably not far off.  In the old days (which for me was circa 8086), the heap and stack grew in opposite directions towards each other, the stack growing from the bottom (end of memory) up, and the heap growing from the top (beginning of user memory) down.

Comment: @Robert is right, and don't forget, the folks inventing these terms were just ordinary slobs like us. So what do you call a pile of stuff that has no particular order to it? Well, "heap" is one thing. (I can think of others :)

Comment: There's a dozen dupes of this question.

Comment: @DeadMG: That's why we have this vote to close thingy, and moderator flags if you don't have enough rep to vote to close.  Failing all that, you can link to a duplicate here in the comments.  In any case, I did a search, and couldn't find any dupes.

Comment: To the close vote - This question is on-topic.  Please see this [recent Meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5524/are-word-origin-questions-on-topic?cb=1) for more details.  Ironically, that meta question was listed in my community bulletin listing for this question.

Comment: @DeadMG: link to some then please, so we can put the dupe in the vote to close form.

Comment: The dup isnt on P.SE, but rather SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660855/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-heap-for-the-free-store and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap

Comment: @GlenH7: I didn't vote to close it as off-topic.  I voted to close as Too Localized, because ... well, who cares but the OP?  It satisfies idle curiosity, but there's nothing in the word origin for "heap" that's going to make *anyone* a better programmer, including the OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I was basing my comment by the [top voted answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5526/53019) and some supporting answers from that particular question...  Of course, the OP hasn't picked an answer yet either.  :-)  I must admit that the answer for this particular question isn't all that illuminating.

Answer (score 7):

From the information found at StackOverflow - [What is the origin of the term “heap” for the free store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660855/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-heap-for-the-free-store) and [Why are two different concepts both called “heap”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap)

This information at least dates back to Knuth in 1975 referencing other (unnamed) authors:

> Several authors began about 1975 to call the pool of available memory
>   a "heap." But in the present series of books, we will use that word
>   only in its more traditional sense related to priority queues.
>   (The Art of Computer Programming - Fundamental Algorithms, 3rd ed., p. 435)

There is also mention of Wijngaarden discussion on Algol in the early 1970s referring to the available memory pool as a heap (`heap` is a reserved word in Algol which is defined in places as "allocate variable some free space from the global heap." - Algol68 dates from 1968).

[Implementing the ALGOL 68 heap](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01935562?LI=true) from 1970 may be of use in tracking down some aspects of word origin, though much if it is behind a paywall.